# Facebook/Whatsapp Webhook is not being verified

Tags: webhooks, whatsapp, facebook-webhooks

I am setting up an app to work with WhatsApp.
In order to do that I need to supply a webhook, per Facebook's specifications.
I did so.
When I try to use Quickstart - Configuration - Webhook - Edit to connect my account/app to my webhook, it says it can't verify the webhook. It doesn't say why.
From debugging my endpoint I can see that it is not even being called.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So this is kind of embarrassing but may be helpful.
You are supposed to supply a callback URL.
I gave it something of the form:

```
www.example.com/webhooks
```

But you have to give it:

```
https://www.example.com/webhooks
```

Answer (score 0):

On the listener end, you need to make sure you are processing the hub.challenge property sent when you set up the webhook.

You can follow along this video with all the steps detailed:
https://youtu.be/0l9lv3-09Fk